# SSRS ZIP LEADING ZERO FOR 4 DIGITS AND NO ZERO FOR 5 DIGITS

Tags: reporting-services

I want to show zip 1111 as 01111 and 11111 as simply 11111 the US zip standard.as for now I did it in two ways,but seems like not a perfect solution 

1.=Right("0"&Fields!Zip.Value,5)

2. custom number =0####
But now my problem is if zip number exceeds the number of digits then how would I apply it say 8 or 10 digits ?

Comment: The zip code is a (mostly) fixed length and shouldn't extend past a maximum of 9 digits.
You could use an IIF formula within RS to find the length of the zip code and add either one or four additional digits, however I'd be inclined to do this in a case statement in the database code.

Can you post your database code?

Comment: The first option you tried is good for US postal codes. Other countries have different formats so there's no single formatting solution for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try 00000 format code. It will display all length of zip codes.
In any case the zip code is less than 5 digits it will always display 5 digit with leading zeroes